# GCE on Container + CloudSQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, coreos

When creating an instance template with a container and running it on GCE, what's the recommended way to connect to a CloudSQL instance from the container?

GCE doesn't allow you to expose ports, and runs the container in host networking mode, so running cloudsql proxy in the background of the container doesn't work either.

Comment: You can use the Cloud SQL proxy docker
image to connect to the Cloud SQL instance. You can
follow the instruction in this article
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-docker
If this does not work, please provide the error message
you receive.

Comment: What is the challenge? You can run cloud sql in your container startup command. Or you can reach your Cloud SQL database on private IP. What is your problem with these solutions?

Comment: The docker host networking mode. Starting cloudsql proxy in the same container as the application isn't allowing the application to connect to the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a timing issue.. sending the cloudsql proxy to the background without waiting for it it initialize was causing the application to not retry connecting to the port.